# Adding ggplot2 legend with many lines using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to make a time series line graph with a different line for each of the 50 states (plus 3 territories), and I want each line to be a different color. I accomplished this by building the ggplot with a for loop like so:

```
plot <- ggplot()
for (i in 1:53) {
  plot <- plot + geom_point(data = filter(equipment_df, state == levels(equipment_df$state)[i]) %>% group_by(year = floor_date(date, "year")) %>% summarize(amount = sum(acquisition_value)), aes(x = year, y = amount), alpha = 0.3, size = 0.3) + 
    geom_line(data = filter(equipment_df, state == levels(equipment_df$state)[i]) %>% group_by(year = floor_date(date, "year")) %>% summarize(amount = sum(acquisition_value)), aes(x = year, y = amount), col = i, alpha = 0.7)
}
plot + scale_x_date(limit = c(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("2020-06-01")))
```

This gives me exactly what I want, minus a legend. The dataset is a bunch of individual items that I want to separate by state and aggregate the value of by year, which is what the row of pipes does. "col = i" gives me the 53 different colors I want.

I understand that ggplot2 automatically makes a legend if you map the colors inside aes(), so I tried that too. However, if I move "col = i" to inside aes(), then every line is the same color and the legend is a solid bar of that color with "53" next to it - it seems like it made a gradient of all one color. I also tried "col = levels(equipment_df$state)[i]". That term returns a two-letter state code like "AK" or "MO", and it worked as intended earlier in the code. When I use that for color, it still makes everything the same color and gives me a legend with only the last state in the list on it. Basically it seems like the for loop only returns the last value when it's inside aes(), even though it's working properly everywhere else.

I'm open to suggestions to totally change my approach, but since I already got almost exactly what I wanted, I'm also looking for 1) a way to manually add a legend to my first approach, and/or 2) an explanation/solution to why the for loop isn't working for color inside aes().

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to guess without an example of your data, but is it difficult to aggregate year within each state in a separate step outside the plot?  Then you can map `color` to the variable directly inside `aes()`.  Even if you can't manipulate the data in a single pipe you could run the manipulation through your loop and then bind it back together prior to plotting (with, e.g., `bind_rows()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that using a for loop is fundamentally he wrong way to create a `ggplot` which maps the color aesthetic to `equipment_df$state`.

Not having your data set I cannot readily verify my code but in principle you want to something like this:

```
data %>% 
group_by(year = floor_date(date, "year"), state) %>%
summarize(amount = sum(acquisition_value)) -> plotData


plot <- ggplot(plotData, aes(x = year, y = amount, color=state, group=state)) +
        geom_point(alpha = 0.3, size = 0.3) +
        geom_line(alpha = 0.7) +
        scale_x_date(limit = c(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("2020-06-01")))
```

The idea is the following: You prepare your dataset for plotting beforehand and by mapping the color aesthetic to amount `ggplot` will automatically color the lines according to their state (and create the corresponding legend).

Comment: This worked, thanks! I knew mapping color to state would give each line a different color but I didn’t know it would create different lines for each state in the first place.

Comment: Actually the individual lines are due to the `group=state` argument!

Comment: Oh, I actually missed that part and didn't have it in my code and it still made individual lines

Comment: Ah even better - I never know when you need group and when not :)